# Joda DateTimeFormat change AM/PM format?

Tags: java, datetime, formatting, jodatime

It formats 'aa' as "AM"/"PM", but I want "a.m."/ "p.m.". Is this possible with the formatter, or is my best bet to manually do a .replace()?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't think too much, easy going to .replace() .